# Can I open two sound cards at the same time on an Android device?

Tags: android, alsa

There is an android device(android TV) connected with iPod via usb. I would like output pcm data which is from usb path to TV's speaker.

In this case, the system would create two pcm device nodes, one is for ALSA sound card(output) and the other is for usb audio(input).

Can Android handle two audio devices at the same time? In other words, does it work well if I open both pcmC0D0p and pcmC1D0c on android?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel drivers used on Android are normal Linux drivers.
So if the kernel has the USB audio driver enabled, and if you actually manage to open both device nodes (the normal Android APIs do not allow to select an audio device), then you will be able to use them both.

Comment: Hello, I know this post is very old, and actually I now encounter the same question. 
There are two audio codec wm8962 on our board. we want to play or record on these two codec at the same time from android apk.
Could you give me some guidance please?
Whether that means we need to modify mediarecorder mediaplayer audioflinger from upper layer application framework to native framework and corresponding services, and finally update SDK for the apk development, right?
I really need your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.